# Image being cut rather than scaled

Tags: html, css

I inserted an image with the img tag, & am styling it with CSS. Changing the width & height of the image only cuts it down, & I lose part of the image. I have also tried making the image smaller in photoshop, which changed nothing on the page. How can I make the image smaller?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle. net/#run&togetherjs=gRmfnlL7By

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS relevant to your issue in order for anyone to help.

Comment: use JSfeddle. Then we can help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=gRmfnlL7By in jsfiddle, the image is not changing size regardless of what I set the height to.

Comment: class="box1" is how I do it, right? That's on there already

Comment: OK, so how do I define the size of the image?

Comment: You can see on my fiddle, I have only specified height, not width

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the image at it's original size, or size it with whatever width:

[here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/Ldzpendo/)

```
<div id="featured">
<img class="box1" src="http://i.imgur.com/okaRdo8.png" />
</div>


#featured {
display:inline-block;
}

#featured .box1 {
    width:auto; /*or whatever width*/
}
```